# Material requirement for excavator bucket, brushes and pins

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

I would like to know what properties would be necessary in a metal material used to construct an mining excavator bucket the brushes and pins for mining coal. I think that hardness and toughness would be necessary for the bucket however the brushes may need to be made of a softer material to save the pins and bucket from wear.

Comment: This seems a bit ... broad.  Would you care to [edit] your question to narrow the scope and better define the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

As with all earth digging equipment, abrasion resistance is important.

For ground engaging tools used to dig coal, particularly underground, the tools must not create sparks when they engage the ground or muck pile due to the potentially explosive environment from methane gas or coal dust.